# SpringData Neo4J - repositories do not alter @GraphId?

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I upgraded to Spring 3.1.2, Neo4J 1.8.RC1 and SpringData 2.1.0.RC3 and I run into the following issue.

Before explaining the problem, here is part of my application context:

```
<!-- Neo4J -->
<neo4j:config storeDirectory="target/graph.db" entityManagerFactory="entityManagerFactory"/>
<neo4j:repositories base-package="***.repository"/>

<!-- H2 -->
<jdbc:embedded-database type="H2" id="accountDataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:scripts/schema.sql" separator=";"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>


<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="accountDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="***.domain" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${database.dialect}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- transactions -->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" />
```

I run a very basic test :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:devinlove-core.xml")
@Transactional
public class MascotRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private MascotRepository mascotRepository;
    private Mascot mascot;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mascot = new Mascot();
        mascot.setName("Tux");
    }

    @Test
    public void when_inserting_then_retrievable() {
        assertThat(mascotRepository).isNotNull();
        mascotRepository.save(mascot);
        assertThat(mascot.getId()).isGreaterThan(0L);
    }
}
```

And the test fails with a NPE. Why isn't mascot ID still null after the save operation?

MascotRepository is defined as follows:

```
public interface MascotRepository extends GraphRepository<Mascot> {}
```

Mascot itself is a very basic NodeEntity:

```
@NodeEntity
@TypeAlias("mascot")
public class Mascot {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Indexed(indexType= FULLTEXT, indexName = "mascotSearch")
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Mascot{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
}
```

I don't know if this can be relevant to the issue, but one of my NodeEntity is partial and therefore is modified by AspectJ (to add basic ActiveRecord methods). Can you confirm only partial NodeEntities are modified this way and not pure Neo4J entities? If not, can it cause conflict with repositories?

If you have any ideas, thanks in advance!
Rolf

Comment: I maybe have a problem with transactions. I see lots of "Outside of transaction, GET value from field class ..." in the logs...

Comment: Where does the NPE occur ? Can you perhaps share your project on github or dropbox for a test-run? Thx

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your support.
Here it is: https://github.com/LateralThoughts/DevInLove/tree/meetup-unstable. just run 'mvn test' to reproduce the problem.

Comment: erratum: run 'cd sources; mvn test' ;)

Comment: I tried it, it works fine for me? Also you have JPA config in your project as well as a JPA TM configured. Can you try if it fails if you make a version of your project without any JPA configuration?

Comment: I'll try that... thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right definition of the transactionManager bean is this:

```
<bean id="jpaTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jtaTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <bean class="org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.SpringTransactionManager">
            <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="userTransaction">
        <bean  class="org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.UserTransactionImpl">
            <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="jpaTransactionManager"/>
            <ref bean="jtaTransactionManager"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```